# Pass initial values to ChoiceField in django formset

Tags: django, formset, formsets

I can't figure out how to populate a django ChoiceField with initial data. Preferrably want to do it in the view, as it will change depending on the parameters I pass to the view.

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    init_ingredients = [{'food':'Candy','amt':12,'units':'cup'},{'food':'Bacon','amt':9,'units':'cup'}]
    IngredientsFormSet = formset_factory(IngredientLineForm, can_delete=True)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = IngredientsFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        ...
    else:
        formset = IngredientsFormSet(initial=init_ingredients)
```

the 'food' field and the 'amt' field populate, but the 'units' field - which is an html Select input does not populate with initial value. Do I need to define choices too? and have the initial value be one of them?

**forms.py**

```
class IngredientLineForm(forms.Form):
    food = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'foods form-control'})) #class = food
    units = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'units form-control'}))
    amt = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'amt form-control'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
    class netadminGlobalFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
        model = netInfo
        form_class = netInfoForm

        def get_initial(self):
            initial = super(netadminGlobalFormView, self).get_initial()
            initial['eth0_ip'] = self.model_instance.get_eth0_ip_stdout
            initial['config_type'] = 'DHCP'
            return initial
```

Note that here:

```
    initial['config_type'] = 'DHCP'
```

I set a value from selection:

```
    # value  displayed value
    config_types=(
       ('DHCP', 'Automatic (DHCP)'),
       ('MANUAL', 'Static (manual)')
    )
```

and form definition includes the following:

```
    class netInfoForm(ModelForm):

        eth0_ip=forms.GenericIPAddressField(protocol='IPv4',
            widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'}),
            max_length=IPv4_addr_chars,
            label=IPv4_addr_html_label,
            help_text='required: i.e. 192.168.111.12 ',
            required=True
    #        ,error_messages={'required': 'Please enter IPv4 address, i.e. 192.168.111.12'}
        )

        config_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=config_types, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
                                        #,initial='MANUAL')
```

and in model:

```
    class netInfo(models.Model):
        eth0_ip     = models.CharField(max_length = IPv4_addr_chars, blank=True, null=False, default=get_eth0_ip_stdout)
        config_type = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=False, null=False, default="DHCP")
```

W/o using initial value 'DHCP' or 'MANUAL' in sample above the choice starts unselected. Also note that initial could be set in form class (commented above).

So, exactly to your questions:

1> Do I need to define choices too?

Yes, choices should be defined in model.

2> and have the initial value be one of them?

Yes, initial values for choices must match your choices definition for form and model.

At least that's so in django 2.0 .

As about question 1) - I can't claim there is no ability to init choices other way, but for my sample answer for question 2) is exactly that - non-matching values ignored (didn't raise exception).